# How to separate google analytics on magento/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, magento, google-analytics

I'd like to track Magento store and Wordpress blog separately, where magento is in root directory and wordpress is in sub-directory e.g www.my-mage-store/wordpress.

Problem I'm having is that I already have GA on magento store and it tracks blog trafic as well, is it possible to separate reports for blog and store visitors somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the GA dashboard, create a custom report, select "Page" from the "Include" dropdown (sub "Filters"), and select "Regex" (in your case, the regex value should be: `^/wordpress/`).

Comment: Thanks for your help I just created the custom report, but data is not showing up yet, do I need to give it a time or this means that I did something wrong?

Comment: Had to add GA tracking code to wordpress (( should start collecting data. Thanks a lot.